# Zoom in-out problems in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, zooming

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed and having problems with zooming or out function. When I activate zoom it generally zooms in the **whole screen** but I only want a zoomed in image of a small area of a screen like **rectangle** or **square**.Generally like the zoom in Windows 10.So how to modify this settings in Ubuntu.The zoomed screen is like this[image]

Comment: I, being visually-impaired, also need this feature.  I have my whole screen at a very large size which presents another problem: most apps don't inspect/respect this setting... so the bottom of the dialogs are inaccessible.  That's really a problem because most dialogs have the "OK", "Cancel", and perhaps "Help" buttons.  So, I'm unable to use those products.. or at least certain features.  There are discussions in AskUbuntu about this issue... but we (in 20.04) do not have Unity (which the anwers address). I'll bookmark this.  I see no one has responded in 4 months.  I hope that changes soon.